# Cannot add a cookie to NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am using Monotouch, and trying to store a NsHttpCookie object in the shared storage of my simulator, to be used for my future requests.
 I am using `NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.SetCookie (NSHttpCookie)` method.

However, after i do this, when i try to retrieve the cookies (via `NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.Cookies`), i see 0 cookies.

In more detail - I am converting a system cookie to NSHttpCookie. After that, i try to write this down with

```
NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.AcceptPolicy = NSHttpCookieAcceptPolicy.Always;
NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.SetCookie (
                       convertSystemCookieToNsCookie(resp.Cookies[0]));
```

When i try to retrieve the cookie with

```
NSHttpCookie[] cookies = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.Cookies;
Console.Out.WriteLine ("Found cookies " + cookies.Length);
```

It says 0 cookie.
I don't see any exceptions anywhere. 
This is the convertSystemCookieToNsCookie method -

```
private NSHttpCookie convertSystemCookieToNsCookie(Cookie cookie) {
        var properties = new NSMutableDictionary ();
        properties.Add (NSHttpCookie.KeyOriginURL, new NSString(cookie.Domain));
        properties.Add (NSHttpCookie.KeyName, new NSString(cookie.Name));
        properties.Add (NSHttpCookie.KeyValue, new NSString(cookie.Value));
        properties.Add (NSHttpCookie.KeyPath, new NSString (cookie.Path));
        NSDate cookieDate = NSDate.FromTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate ((
            cookie.Expires - (new DateTime (2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))).TotalSeconds);
        properties.Add (NSHttpCookie.KeyExpires, cookieDate);
        return new NSHttpCookie (properties);
    }
```

Any idea what could i be doing wrong? 
Thanks much!

Comment: What's `convertSystemCookieToNsCookie` ? your own code ? can we see it ?

Comment: updated the code with my method. thanks!

Comment: Might be unrelated but did you try the `NSHttpCookie` constructor that accept a `Cookie` instance ? https://github.com/mono/maccore/blob/master/src/Foundation/NSHttpCookie.cs#L82

Comment: Great :) I added it as an answer so it will be easier to find (for others). Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSHttpCookie` has [constructor](https://github.com/mono/maccore/blob/master/src/Foundation/NSHttpCookie.cs#L82) that accept a .NET `System.Net.Cookie` instance that can be used to avoid code like `convertSystemCookieToNsCookie`.

What *likely* happens is that an error while creating the `NSHttpCookie` from an `NSMutableDictionary` will return a empty handle (`IntPtr.Zero`) and that won't be added to shared storage. The helper .ctor was added to avoid such problems.

Comment: poupou, another problem now - This ways, the cookie is not persisting on my simulator. I am writing the cookie, and can find it on the device in that particular run. However, when i 'stop' the app, rebuild and run it, it cannot find the cookie again. IS this the expected behavior? thanks again!

Comment: Ok, i think i found a bug in the constructor that you pointed out. Its dropping the 'expired' field from the cookie, and the NSHttpCookie that its creating out is a session cookie (while the System.Net.Cookie object has an expires date)

Comment: The code is there - but Apple's NSHttpCookie will return null for `expiresDate` on **session** cookies, ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookie_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Well, the cookie that the server is sending is certainly not a session cookie - cookie.Discard is False and cookie.Expires is a valid date. S o are you sure there is nothing wrong with the constructor?

Comment: The code is there https://github.com/mono/maccore/blob/master/src/Foundation/NSHttpCookie.cs#L117 so it should be given to `NSHttpCookie` and I knew one reason why it *might* not be given back (there could be other reasons or a bug somewhere). Could you create a test case and file a bug report on http://bugzilla.xamarin.com ?

Comment: Thanks, i'll do that. Meanwhile, any workarounds around this? Should i get back to the approach of using my own custom way of getting NsHttpCookie from a system cookie?

Comment: We need to know what's wrong ? the existing code or what `NSHttpCookie` return (if provided at creation time). The first should be easy to workaround (needs a test case) while the later *might* not be fixable.